# How to use PushNotificationTrigger in Background Task in universal windows app

Tags: windows-10-universal

I searched a lot but I didn't get any documentation or example that can help me to use PushNotificationTrigger in Background Task like we use SystemTrigger and TimeTrigger.

I want to receive the Toast Notifications when my app is closed. Notifications are coming to windows but don't know how to handle that in background.
Anybody who had worked on PushNotifications in Universal windows app please provide some sample or document to handle the notifications.

[This is I am getting in Lifecycle Events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88P6a.png)
This is the code I am using to register the Task

```
if(!Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.Any(i => i.Value.Name == "PushBackgroundTask"))
{
   var result = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
   var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
   builder.Name = "PushBackgroundTask";
   builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(NotificationActionBackgroundTask.NotificationActionBackgroundTask).FullName;
   builder.SetTrigger(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Background.PushNotificationTrigger());
   BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be a little confused here. When using `PushNotification`, the server can push 4 kinds of notification to your device: [Toast, Tile, Badge and Raw Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-choosing-a-notification-delivery-method#Notification_delivery_methods__overview).

The front three notifications will be received by Notification center and handled by system. Raw Notification is a push notification that does not involve UI, its contents can be used in an app's background task.

> I want to receive the Toast Notifications when my app is closed.

So no, if you want to in background task handle the PushNotifications using `PushNotificationTrigger`, you can only handle the Row Notifications. You can refer to [PushNotificationTrigger class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.background.pushnotificationtrigger.aspx), this class represents an object that invokes a background work item on the app in response to the receipt of a raw notification.

> Unlike other push notifications, raw notifications don't have a specified format. The content of the payload is entirely app-defined.

So if your push a toast notification, you don't need to handle it in your background task, it will be handled by action center. But you can handle a Raw Notification in your background task and toast it manually.

For the information about how to use `PushNotificaitonTrigger` with `Raw notification`, you can refer to [Raw notification overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-raw-notification-overview), and for toast in the background task, you can refer to the official [Notifications sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Notifications).

**Update**

To debug the project with lifecycle events, you can take a look at the following screen shot:
[image]

When debuging, you apps lifecycle is depended on the vs tool, but you can click this red circle part to debug your app's lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks Grace, it really help me to sort out about notifications, concept is clear to me now.

Comment: But one more issue arises now, that, when I register the background task with PushNotificationTrigger it is not showing me any background Task on Lifecycle Events in Visual Studio while debugging. Is it because Background Task is not registered correctly? And why always it is loading symbols and VS is not able to load many of them and asks me to upload (for ex. frameworkapplication.g.cpp not found)? Can you please help me here.

Comment: @AnkitSaini, you mean you want to debug the background task? I will update a screen shot to  show you how to debug with life-cycle events. "And why always it is loading symbols and VS is not able to load many of them and asks me to upload ", I don't understand this.

Comment: Grace Feng, I updated the question with screenshot and the code I am using to register the background task, please take a look, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AnkitSaini, I didn't find any problem from your code, have you correctly added declarations in your app's manifest?  You can refer to [Create and register a background task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/create-and-register-a-background-task). And if you have other questions about background task, please open a new question on SO, we can continue to help.

Comment: Yes it is different question, Okay Grace Feng, I had fired one more question on SO. please help me there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38199110/background-task-using-pushnotificationtrigger